# How can I have a status component display the state of the app to the user using redux without having many dispatch calls?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm working on an application that calls multiple APIs for data, and generally waits for a lot of stuff.  It also uses some awesome new technologies, like IPFS.

I have a React component that displays the current status of what's going on behind the scenes and displays a message with an icon of thumbs up, an hourglass etc.

A comparable command line "component" would be the rapidfire scrolling that npm does when installing something -- there is a ton of stuff that happens and npm displays it.  That's exactly what I want to do but in a website.  Well, maybe not *exactly* what I want, because a lot of that data is scrolled way too quickly to be useful, but then again I would have 100-200 different possible calls in this application (assuming the user executes every possible action in this app which won't happen).

The way I have this setup works.  I have a redux `status` reducer which updates the status when various actions are dispatched.

Excerpt:

```
const status = (
  state = {
  message: 'idle',
  numTasks: 0,
  numPullRequests: 0,
  txSubmitted: false
},
 action
) => {
  switch (action.type) {
   case actions.SUBMIT_TASK:
    return Object.assign({}, state, {
      message: 'Adding task to blockchain',
      txSubmitted: true
  })
case actions.RECEIVE_TASK:
  return Object.assign({}, state, {
    message: 'Received tasks'
  })
case actions.RECEIVE_TASKS:
  return Object.assign({}, state, {
    message: 'Received tasks'
  })
case actions.REQUEST_PULLREQUESTS_INSTANCE:
  return Object.assign({}, state, {
    message: 'Awaiting pull requests contract'
  })
case actions.SET_DEFAULT_STATUS:
  return Object.assign({}, state, {
    message: 'idle',
    txSubmitted: false
  })
default:
  return state
```

I reuse a few actions that existed and were already called.  But I unfortunately created actions to really capture all of the different status changes.

Updating this component as often as I'd like has resulted in too many `dispatch(someActionThatUpdatesTheStatus())` calls.

So I wonder is there a way to do what I'm trying to do without having to `dispatch` actions everywhere?

I looked for packages -- found one that does notifications, but those are in response to *user input*, not various behind-the-scenes status changes (querying API-1, querying API-2, receiving this data, etc.)